# how to Embed a function into read -p command

Tags: bash

I want to know is it possible to place a function inside a read -p command.

```
flashRed="\033[5;31;40m"
red="\033[31;40m"
none="\033[0m"

question(){
  echo -e $none"Do you wan to remove"  $flashRed"$1?" $none
}
 read -p $question response
```

Comment: not clear... see if https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better formulation of your question would be

> Is it possible to supply the output of a bash function as an argument for `read -p`.

The answer is yes. Use *substitution* `$()`:

```
read -p "$(question argument) " response
```

Where `argument` is the string which will be accessed as `$1` by your function. The argument can be a variable, for instance `"$(question "$file") "`.

But even if it was not possible, you could simulate what `-p` does. It just prints the given string without a newline.

```
echo -en "${none}Do you wan to remove ${flashRed}argument${none}? "
read response
```

`-n` disables the trailing newline of `echo`.

Or even better (because not all `echo` implementations support `-e` and `-n`):

```
printf "$none%s $flashRed%s$none? " "Do you wan to remove" "argument"
read response
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked when tried.

```
flashRed="\033[5;31;40m"
red="\033[31;40m"
none="\033[0m"

question(){
  echo -e $none"Do you wan to remove"  $flashRed"$1?" $none
}
 read -p "$(question $1) " response
```

Comment: Please include details as to what you've done to fix the issue. As it stands, it's very hard to see the change you made (adding quotation marks and $1 in the last line).

Comment: I just followed the answer given by @Socowi. I created the function (question in this case). the read statement with -e will require (" ") and $1 is the argument.